# Contribution of a loop to the degree of a vertex in a graph

Tags: graph-theory, definition

#### Prehistory

I've recently started learning graph theory in my institute (as a part of discrete mathematics course). During a lecture the professor had given a definition for a **local degree of a vertex** which was:

> *A number of edges incident to the vertex*

And told us that *loops contribute **1** to the degree of a vertex*.
There was also a theorem defined during a lecture (some kind of handshaking lemma?):

> If graph G is an undirected finite graph *without loops*, then the number of vertices with odd local degree is even.
>   Shortly: $|V_o|$ is even.

But as I had studied graph theory myself before, I knew that loops contribute **2** to the degree of a vertex (even some sources, listed below, confirm this statement).
So I asked him, why can't we just fix up that a loop contributes **2** to the degree, and remove the condition (*without loops*) from the theorem.
He answered me that if we define a degree of a vertex as *a number of edges incident to the vertex* then the fact that a loop contributes **2** to the degree of a vertex is not a part of the formal mathematical definition, so loops contribute **1** to the degree of a vertex.

#### Questions

- Is there a difference between definitions of *local degree of a vertex* and *a degree of a vertex*?
- Can a side-note that *loops are counted twice in the degree of a vertex* be the part of the formal mathematical definition of a graph vertex?
- If it can't, is there such definition, where loops are counted twice?
- Are loops counted twice just for a simplification of some theorems?
- Does this depend from a context?

#### Sources

Sources, which **do confirm** that *"a loop is considered to contribute 2 to the degree of a vertex"*:

- [Wikipedia : Degree (graph theory)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(graph_theory))
- [Graph Theory With Applications (J. A. Bondy and U. S. R. Mury), page 10](http://www.maths.lse.ac.uk/Personal/jozef/LTCC/Graph_Theory_Bondy_Murty.pdf)
- [An answer to the similar question on math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1013116/57056)

Sources, which **say nothing** about a loop in the definition of a degree of a vertex:

- [Wikipedia : Glossary of graph theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_graph_theory)
- [The Algorithm Design Manual, Second Edition (Steven S. Skiena), page 150, paragraph 3](http://sist.sysu.edu.cn/~isslxm/DSA/textbook/Skiena.-.TheAlgorithmDesignManual.pdf)
- [Graph Theory, Electronic Edition 2000 (Reinhald Diestrel), page 5](http://www.esi2.us.es/~mbilbao/pdffiles/DiestelGT.pdf)

Comment: It’s simply a question of where you want to situate the awkwardness. I prefer to make the definition of *degree of a vertex* a little more complicated and count a loop as contributing $2$ to the degree, since it makes everything else a bit simpler. Your professor evidently prefers to keep the definition of degree as simple as possible, but at the cost of complicating the statement of some theorems. Both approaches are feasible if carried out consistently.

Comment: Further, the definition of "pendant vertex" or "leaf vertex" is more complicated  using the "local degree" definition.  It is nonstandard.  It's certainly not wrong, however, and by using a different term the professor is trying to minimize confusion with the standard term.

Comment: I think of the degree of a vertex $v$ as the number of half-edges incident with $v.$ Of course, if an edge is a loop, both halves are incident with the same vertex, so the loop contributes $2$ to the degree of that vertex. And I don't understand the term "local degree". If you put a vertex under the microscope, you won't be able to tell the difference between a loop and two ordinary edges.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I've added some more sources, as promised.
I had an assumption that it doesn't matter if it's $1$ or $2$, and your comment seems to confirm this, @BrianM.Scott. But still, it's a bit weird for me, as I am used that most of the definitions are strict and cannot assume anything else but it's said in them.

Comment: @bof, according to [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VertexDegree.html) there's no difference: `The vertex degree is also called the local degree or valency.`